# traffic going through lo interface checking every 4 ports

Tags: debian, networking, chrome, loopback, tshark

I have noticed that there' s **always** traffic going on on my loopback interface. It's not a lot but I don't know where it's coming from and I'd like to stop it.

There's syn request going from port X to port 9229, then a rst/ack response. Half a second later I get the same from X+4 to 9229, then X+8 and so on?

Is there some service that could be originating it? This is debian testing... and updated a few days ago.

Update 1:
I was able to capture this with netstat:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      1 127.0.0.1:60024         127.0.0.1:9229          SYN_SENT    314481/chromium --s
```

And this process has:

```
/usr/lib/chromium/chromium --show-component-extension-options --enable-gpu-rasterization --no-default-browser-check --disable-pings --media-router=0 --enable-remote-extensions --load-extension
```

What the hell is chromium doing?

Update 2:
A HTTP request is sent:

```
GET /json/version HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9229
```

But what is chromium trying to find?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Chromium default nodejs inspector for debugging purposes, probably enabled by default.